# How do I use svg-url-loader with webpack to properly bundle svg files without a framework

Tags: css, svg, webpack

I am  having trouble using the loader "svg-url-loader" with webpack to bundle svg files for production in my WebApp. My svg icons don't seem to display

In chrome dev tools I can see that a url is generated

```
.background-icon-github {
    background-image: url(http://localhost:63342/dist/9be8bc0….svg);
}
```

but I still don't see the icon, nor can I display it in "sources" in chrome dev tools

This is my current setup

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const LodashModuleReplacementPlugin = require('lodash-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'main.js'
    },
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: [
                    'source-map-loader',
                    'babel-loader'
                ],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg/,
                use: {
                    loader: "svg-url-loader",
                    options: {},
                },
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "@popperjs/core": path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js"),
            "bootstrap": path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.min.js"),
        },
    },
};

module.exports = config;
```

wtf.css:

```
.background-icon-journal-richtext {
    background-image: url("./assets/beaker.svg");
}.background-icon-play-btn {
    background-image: url("./node_modules/bootstrap-icons/icons/play-btn.svg");
}.background-icon-github {
    background-image: url("./node_modules/bootstrap-icons/icons/github.svg");
}.background-icon-globe2 {
    background-image: url("./node_modules/bootstrap-icons/icons/globe2.svg");
}
```

index.js:

```
import {setupUserPrompts} from "./modules/setupApp.js";
import {setupDiagramToolbar} from "./modules/diagramToolbar.js";
require("svg-url-loader!./assets/beaker.svg");
require("svg-url-loader!./node_modules/bootstrap-icons/icons/play-btn.svg");
require("svg-url-loader!./node_modules/bootstrap-icons/icons/github.svg");
require("svg-url-loader!./node_modules/bootstrap-icons/icons/globe2.svg");
import "./wtf.css";
import "./SassFormStyle.scss";


setupUserPrompts();
setupDiagramToolbar();
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">



    <title>Serial Dilution Diagram Generator User Prompts</title>

  </head>

  
  <body id="mainBody">

    <div id="navigation">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills justify-content-center">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">
            <span>Report</span>
            <div class="nav-icon background-icon-journal-richtext"></div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <span>Showcase</span>
            <div class="nav-icon background-icon-play-btn" ></div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <span>GitLab</span>
            <div class="nav-icon background-icon-github" ></div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <span>Website</span>
            <div class="nav-icon background-icon-globe2" ></div>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- some other html that defines the layout -->

    <script async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es-module-shims@1/dist/es-module-shims.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "@popperjs/core": "/node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
        "bootstrap": "/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.min.js"
      }
    }
    </script>
    <script type="module" src="/dist/main.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

example of one of the svg files:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-github" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M8 0C3.58 0 0 3.58 0 8c0 3.54 2.29 6.53 5.47 7.59.4.07.55-.17.55-.38 0-.19-.01-.82-.01-1.49-2.01.37-2.53-.49-2.69-.94-.09-.23-.48-.94-.82-1.13-.28-.15-.68-.52-.01-.53.63-.01 1.08.58 1.23.82.72 1.21 1.87.87 2.33.66.07-.52.28-.87.51-1.07-1.78-.2-3.64-.89-3.64-3.95 0-.87.31-1.59.82-2.15-.08-.2-.36-1.02.08-2.12 0 0 .67-.21 2.2.82.64-.18 1.32-.27 2-.27.68 0 1.36.09 2 .27 1.53-1.04 2.2-.82 2.2-.82.44 1.1.16 1.92.08 2.12.51.56.82 1.27.82 2.15 0 3.07-1.87 3.75-3.65 3.95.29.25.54.73.54 1.48 0 1.07-.01 1.93-.01 2.2 0 .21.15.46.55.38A8.012 8.012 0 0 0 16 8c0-4.42-3.58-8-8-8z"/>
</svg>
```